# Angular performance issue with ng-repeat and directives

Tags: javascript, html, angularjs, performance

I am currently working on a table that has 500 rows. Each row has 5 cells. Each cell is a directive. Rendering this table takes around 3 seconds and it locks up the browser.

[image: Timeline]

99% of the time is spent in the "Parse HTML" function which I assume parses the HTML for directives. (There are a lot of Parse HTML functions when I scroll down. I'm guessing its around 2500, can't find a way to calculate it).

A plnkr link where the you can see the issue using chrome dev tools (spending most of the time in parse HTML): http://plnkr.co/edit/UouSapMYGgCNy7jEhlR6?p=preview

How would I go about optimizing this without concatting the HTML string for every row manually.

```
       // Code goes here
  angular
    .module('app', [])
    .directive('cellOne', function() {
      return {
        scope: {
          data: '='
        },
        templateUrl: 'cell.html'
      };
    })
    .directive('cellTwo', function() {
      return {
        scope: {
          data: '='
        },
        templateUrl: 'cell2.html'
      };
    })
    .directive('row', function($compile) {
      return {
        compile: function compile() {
          return {
            pre: function preLink(scope, element) {

              var html = '';
              html += '<cell-one data=row[0]></cell-one>'
              html += '<cell-two data=row[1]></cell-two>'
              html += '<cell-one data=row[2]></cell-one>'
              html += '<cell-two data=row[3]></cell-two>'
              html += '<cell-two data=row[4]></cell-two>'
              var el = angular.element(html);
              var linkFunction = $compile(el);

              element.append(el);
              linkFunction(scope);
            }
          }
        }
      }
    })
    .controller('controller', function($scope) {
      $scope.data = [];
      // Fill the data map with random data
      $scope.refresh = function() {
        for (var i = 0; i < 500; ++i) {
          $scope.data[i] = {};
          for (var j = 0; j < 5; ++j) {
            $scope.data[i][j] = Math.random();
          }
        }
      }
      $scope.refresh()
    });
```

Answer (score 1):

It's a fairly well known fact that Angular starts to have performance issues when you have more than ~2000 watchers (which are responsible for handling your data-binding). In your case, you've got at least 2500.

Reducing the number of data bindings will definitely help. Angular recently introduced one-time data bindings that you can take advantage of if the data being bound isn't completely dynamic.

I'd suggest taking a look at [Speeding up AngularJS apps with simple optimizations](http://www.binpress.com/tutorial/speeding-up-angular-js-with-simple-optimizations/135) for more information.

Comment: I already am doing one-way data binding using {{:: cell.data }}. I've attached a plnkr link where this issue is visible using chrome dev tools (takes 1s to render where most of the time is spent in the parse HTML function)

Comment: @Peeter - You may also want to consider moving your `row` template to a separate file that can be compiled and cached. I'm guessing that would save time on rendering HTML as well.

Answer (score 1):

As Justin metioned, reducing watches helps and $compile is very expensive.  When I look at this code, two specific things jump out:

1)  Use of '='.  This is two-way binding, but if the cellOne and cellTwo directives are not going to change the row, this creates unnecessary watches for each cell. (Note that these watches are set up even if you use the ::data syntax when doing interpolation in your template).  Changing to '&' is a quick win.

2)  $compile is run for each row.  $compile (and $parse) are relatively expensive.  Not sure why you don't just do that with the template parameter, but if for some reason you need to use $compile, call it once and cache the link function, rather than calling $compile in each instance of the directive.  link -> fast.....$compile -> slow (comparatively).  Of the two optimizations, this one should have the most impact.

[Here is a plunk with these optimizations applied](http://plnkr.co/edit/5Dnnm4EUsCYNJMi4If9x?p=preview) for comparison purposes.

```
 angular
    .module('app', [])
    .directive('cellOne', function() {
      return {
        scope: {
          data: '&'
        },
        templateUrl: 'cell.html'
      };
    })
    .directive('cellTwo', function() {
      return {
        scope: {
          data: '&'
        },
        templateUrl: 'cell2.html'
      };
    })
    .directive('row', function() {
      return {
        template: '<cell-one data=row[0]></cell-one>' +
                  '<cell-two data=row[1]></cell-two>' +
                  '<cell-one data=row[2]></cell-one>' +
                  '<cell-two data=row[3]></cell-two>' +
                  '<cell-two data=row[4]></cell-two>'
      }
    })


<p>cell1: {{:: data() }}</p>
```